# how to show my custom collection view for other devices same

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, custom-cell, collectionview

I created a collection view custom cell like this:

[image]

on iPhone 6.

But when I run my app on iPhone 5 or 5se my cell is like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: @YouraKant - cell placement in collection view has nothing to do with constraints. ismailtsn92 - it seems that your cell spacing is too big. It may be good enough to fit two columns on iPhone 6, but on iPhone 5 collectionview rearanges automatically into one column. Try adjusting cell spacing

Answer (score 1):

If you want a decent amount of control over the layout of your `UICollectionView` you should have your viewController (or whoever is the `UICollectionViewDelegate`) also conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.  This will allow you to set cell size, margins, spacing between items, etc.  It is a very easy way to make the cells dynamically sized or spaced.  See [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout) for more specifications.